# Sitecore redirect module auto-generated redirects have wrong requested url

Tags: module, redirect

Sitecore 8.2 update 3. Single site. Redirect Module: https://github.com/thecadams/301RedirectModule
The redirect module is automatically creating the redirect rules when an item's url changes, but it has the full sitecore path for the "Requested Url" vs the actual url visitors would be visiting, therefore none of the auto-generated ones work.

So, when I rename /pageOne to /pageTwo, the requested url in the auto-generated redirect is "/sitecore/content/siteName/home/pageOne" instead of "/pageOne". How do I reconfigure the module to create the correct urls?

Comment: Can you provide more details about which one of the many redirect modules you are using?

Comment: I'm not sure how to identify it. It was setup by a partner for us. Do you know of a way for me to identify it?

Comment: You would need to find the parts that make it work (such as the dlls and configs) and match those with what you can find online. Perhaps it came from one posted on the Sitecore Marketplace or on GitHub. Best course would be check with the partner and find out exactly what you need without all the guesswork.

Comment: I updated my post with a link to the module used. @MichaelWest